# Check inheritance in nodejs

Tags: node.js, inheritance, ecmascript-6

What is the best way to check inheritance in nodejs?

I'm trying to use `instanceof` in a instance of a class of another module that inherits a class for this module.

**file a.js**

```
    class A{

    }

    class B extends A{

    }

    var b = new B();

    b instanceof A ///this work
    global.c instanceof A //this doesn't work

    module.exports = A;
```

**file c.js**

```
var A = require("./a");

class C extends A{

}

global.c = new C();
```

Comment: Is `global.c` defined where you use it? Looking at your code, it would not seem so. What happens if you move your `global.c instanceof A` to the end of `c.js`?

Comment: i have a list of objects that run in every request and i can't control where the object is created when i run the instance of for a type crated in a external file it return false for me.

Comment: You'll need a different approach then. If you cannot control load order then relying on load order will fail.

Comment: the porblem isn't the load order, i think that is because the instance is created externaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of loading issue! When you load class C, it request class A and it is run before the C is defined.

I have tried it myself, if I did it as you mentioned and requested both classes, the second one comparision failed.

However this one works:

a.js

```
class A{
    callMeLaterAligator(){
        console.log(b instanceof A) ///this work
        console.log(global.c instanceof A) //this now work
    }
}

class B extends A{

}

var b = new B();

module.exports = A;
```

c.js

```
var A = require("./a");

class C extends A{

}

global.c = new C();
```

The main method

```
require('services/c');
const a = require('services/a');
const aInst = new a();
aInst.callMeLaterAligator();
```

having output

```
true
true
```

---

To better understand whats going on, I have created this example

a.js

```
console.log('Hello, I am class A and I am not yet defined');
class A{

}

class B extends A{

}

var b = new B();

console.log('Hello, I am class A and I will compare something');
console.log(b instanceof A) ///this work
console.log(global.c instanceof A) //this doesn't work

module.exports = A;
```

c.js

```
console.log('Hello, I am class C and I am not yet defined');

var A = require("./a");

console.log('Hello, I am class C and I will now try to defined myself');

class C extends A{

}

console.log('Hello, I am class C and I am defined');
global.c = new C();

console.log('Hello, I am class C and I am in global.c');
```

server.js

```
require('services/c');
```

Having this output

```
Hello, I am class C and I am not yet defined
Hello, I am class A and I am not yet defined
Hello, I am class A and I will compare something
true
false
Hello, I am class C and I will now try to defined myself
Hello, I am class C and I am defined
Hello, I am class C and I am in global.c
```

---

If you change it to require "a" first, then the C is not loaded at all

server.js change :

```
require('services/a');
```

Having this output

```
Hello, I am class A and I am not yet defined
Hello, I am class A and I will compare something
true
false
```

Comment: i moved the baseclass to another file and works, thanks